# CMMotionActivityManager is unable to detect Automotive mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7, core-motion

I am using Core Motion Framework for detecting the device activity.

i.e. Walking, Running, Automotive, Stationary

The main issue is i am able to detect walking and running with great accuracy but my device is not able to detect the Automotive mode.

Here is my code

```
var motionActivityManager: CMMotionActivityManager?
if CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable() {
            motionActivityManager?.startActivityUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {
                activityData
                in
                if activityData!.walking == true {
                    self.lblActivityStatus?.text = "Walking"
                } else if activityData!.running == true {
                    self.lblActivityStatus?.text = "Running"
                } else if activityData!.automotive == true {
                    self.lblActivityStatus?.text = "Automotive"
                } else if activityData!.stationary == true {
                    self.lblActivityStatus?.text = "Stationary"
                }
                print("Activity Data: ", activityData)
            })
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your phone is in automotive mode? (Probably it just does not detect it)

Comment: yes i tried it while i was driving car. it shows either stationary or walking.

Comment: Only because you are driving a car, does not mean that the phone correctly detects this. Have you crosschecked with another app if the phone is correctly detecting it?

Comment: yes i have tried many libraries from git like https://github.com/AmbientStatus/AmbientStatus

Comment: my main goal is to detect driving mode using hardware only not using location services for battery drain issue.

Comment: Do you have Locstion enabled globally on your device?  Detecting automotive mode requires GPS support in the device to measure velocity

Comment: YES GPS is always on and device is 5S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer by testing the same app on multiple devices. 
the m7 chip on first generation device is not working properly for particularly "Automotive" mode.
When i was testing on 5s and ipad air, it was not detecting Automotive mode as it should detect. But testing the same app with iphone 6 Plus, it worked fine.
so the problem was with device not with framework.

Comment: how to detect the iphone version (i.e., iPhone 5s or ipad air) in code?